# Responsive design site title, and slider block

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have just make a responsive design, but there are 2 mistakes. One that when window is resized to different size, entire website will automatically resize, but Heading title and slider doesn't resize. But if i reload it, it will resize.

I have made different css rules of font sizes and slider height, which don't work without reload. You can see online website at: http://www.itmediagroup.lt you see slider, change window size, then u will see a problem, when reload website, and see all changes, I think all bugs are on my css, but i dont know how to fix it.

P.S fontsize i was trying to do in percent, but then the size of font is too small.

Comment: Font doesn't resize with browser, even if you declare the font in percentage. You have define different `fontsize` pixel values for different screen sizes using media queries or use JavaScript plugins like http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can either set font sizes for elements using media queries, javascript ([fittext.js](http://fittextjs.com/)) or you can use css viewport units. For example;

**Viewport unit syntax**

- 1vw: 1% of viewport width
- 1vh: 1% of viewport height
- 1vmin: 1vw or 1vh, whatever is smallest
- 1vmax: 1vw or 1vh, whatever is largest

It is supported by most new browsers but can be made more "bulletproof" by using [**VminPolly**](https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly)

[Some good info and examples here](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)